# What should I do to effects feature from using the Blend?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, effects, blend

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I don't see effect feature in Blend 2013. What should I do to effects feature from using the Blend?

Comment: have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171012.aspx ?

Comment: I've installed sdk 8.0 but effects feature does not appear in blend.